# MySQL: сортировка по двум полям

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста как с помощью MySQL, можно выполнить двойную сортировку?

Есть таблица наименованием фруктов(поле `title`) и их количества в штуках(поле `count`):

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | title     | count |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 | Апельсины |     7 |
|  2 | Ананасы   |    12 |
|  3 | Абрикосы  |    15 |
|  4 | Авокадо   |     2 |
|  5 | Айва      |     4 |
|  6 | Аннона    |     6 |
|  7 | Алыча     |     3 |
|  8 | Араза     |    31 |
|  9 | Гранат    |    15 |
| 10 | Груша     |    18 |
| 11 | Яблоки    |     7 |
| 12 | Арбуз     |    26 |
| 13 | Дыня      |    27 |
| 14 | Киви      |    41 |
| 15 | Лайм      |    23 |
| 16 | Манго     |    22 |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

Мне нужно отсротировать количество от большего к меньшему и выбрать только 10 записей:

```
SELECT * FROM fruits ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10
```

Я получил таблицу:

```
+----+----------+------------+
| id | title    | count_advt |
+----+----------+------------+
| 14 | Киви     |         41 |
|  8 | Араза    |         31 |
| 13 | Дыня     |         27 |
| 12 | Арбуз    |         26 |
| 15 | Лайм     |         23 |
| 16 | Манго    |         22 |
| 10 | Груша    |         18 |
|  9 | Гранат   |         15 |
|  3 | Абрикосы |         15 |
|  2 | Ананасы  |         12 |
+----+----------+------------+
```

Теперь мне нужно отсортировать поле title по алфавиту, чтобы получилось:

```
+----+----------+------------+
| id | title    | count_advt |
+----+----------+------------+
|  3 | Абрикосы |         15 |
|  2 | Ананасы  |         12 |
|  8 | Араза    |         31 |
| 12 | Арбуз    |         26 |
| 14 | Киви     |         41 |
|  9 | Гранат   |         15 |
| 10 | Груша    |         18 |
| 13 | Дыня     |         27 |
| 15 | Лайм     |         23 |
| 16 | Манго    |         22 |
+----+----------+------------+
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать средствами MySQL?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(SELECT * FROM `fruits` ORDER BY `count` DESC LIMIT 10) ORDER BY `title` ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL умеет сортировать по двум полям :)

```
SELECT * FROM fruits ORDER BY count DESC, title ASC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Умеет, но в данном случае результатом этого запроса получится другая таблица. Поле title не отсортируется по алфавиту